# How to make variable type polymorphism work?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have a template Node which returns data of type T.

```
template <class T> Node
{
public: 
     virtual const T& GetData() = 0;
};
```

And I want to have derived classes RefNode, and ValueNode that contain Pointers to data, and actual data. So that I can choose whether to work with a copy of data or to work on actual data in a node.

```
template<class T> class RefNode : public Node<T>
{
public: 
    RefNode(T *_data) : data(_data) { }
    const T& GetData() { return *data; }
protected:
    DataType *data;
};

template<class T> class ValueNode : public Node<T>
{
public: 
    ValueNode(const T&_data) : data(_data) { }
    const T& GetData() { return data; }
protected:
    T data;
};
```

I know that templates can't have virtual methods, but I just wanted to illustrate the effect that I wanted to get. The effect that I wanted to get is:

//for class Vector

```
Vector v, *c;
c = new Vector();
Node<Vector>* node = new RefNode<Vector>(c);
Node<Vector>* node2 = new ValueNode<Vector>(a);

node2->GetData(); //calls ValueNode<Vector>'s GetData();
node->GetData(); //calls RefNode<Vector>'s GetData();
```

Is there any way in C++ to achieve this kind of behaviour?

**EDIT:**

I would use GetData() like this:

```
Vector *vecarr[9];

Node<Vector>* nodes[10];
nodes[0] = new RefNode<Vector>(vecarr[0]);
nodes[1] = new ValueNode<Vector>(Vector(2,3)); //non reference vector
nodes[2] = new RefNode<Vector>(vecarr[1]);
nodes[3] = new RefNode<Vector>(vecarr[2]);
.....

void processPositionNodes(Node<Vector> **nodes, int n)
{
   for(int i=0; i< n; i++)  //iterate over all nodes
   {
      Vector vec = nodes[i]->GetData();
      //do something with vec

   }
}
```

I want to be able to change the type of data the Node contains, because I want to implement several graph algorithms dealing with different types of data, (Vectors, scalars..)

Comment: Templates *can* have virtual functions.

Comment: "I know that templates can't have virtual methods" -- uh what? You're likely thinking of *templated* virtual functions.

Comment: the question is: how do you suppose to use the result of such call GetData() when you receive it? I'm probably wrong, but I don't think you really want a polymorphism based solution. What you probably want is to be able to "inject" a policy into the node, which should be able to change the behaviour with respect to the return type of the GetData member. If you confirm that this would be a solution for you I can work out an answer based on this. Otherwise, please add an example as to how you suppose to use the output of the GetData

Comment: As an aside, `RefNode` when it both takes a pointer and stores a pointer is a bit of a misnomer.  C++ has both references and pointers.

Comment: I Edited my post with an example of how i might use GetData(). You are right I meant templated virtual functions, that return variable type arguments.

Comment: Your code is almost fine as is, modulo a few typos and minor issues. What exactly is not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works just fine (there are some minor and unrelevant changes to your version):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Node
{
public: 
     virtual const T& GetData() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class RefNode : public Node<T>
{
public: 
    RefNode(T *_data) : data(_data) { *data = 5; }
    const T& GetData() { return *data; }
protected:
    T *data;
};

template<class T> class ValueNode : public Node<T>
{
public: 
    ValueNode(const T&_data) : data(_data) { data = 5; }
    const T& GetData() { return data; }
protected:
    T data;
};

int main(){
    double data;
    Node<double>* rn = new RefNode<double>(&data);
    Node<double>* rv = new ValueNode<double>(data);

    const double& a = rn->GetData();
    const double& b = rv->GetData();

    cout << a << '\t' << b << endl;
}
```

However, there are some potential issues with this code: lack of virtual destructor in class Node, lack of copy ctor, dtor, and operator= in class RefNode

Comment: I'm afraid I was off-track with the previous answer, I'm leaving it there. Tell me if this solves your problem and if the previous one is off-track, in that case I'll delete it at once.

Comment: Yes, thank you! This solves my problem, the CRTP is not suitable for my purposes because I need to be able to call derived class functions from pointer of base class type, i.e. I needed dynamic binding.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, templates can indeed have virtual functions. However this is not going to solve your problem. In fact, you would need those functions to have different return types.

This is a possible template-based solution to your problem, it might not be the most elegant but you (we) can work on this basis

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, template<typename> class Accessor, template<typename> class Traits>
class Node{
    public:
        Node() : data(5.){}
        typedef typename Traits<T>::type getType;
        getType get(){
           return static_cast<Accessor<T>*>(this)->implementation();
        }
        virtual ~Node(){}
    protected:
        T data;
};

template <typename T>
struct TraitsP{
    typedef T* type;
};

template <typename T>
class PointerAccessor : public Node<T, PointerAccessor, TraitsP>{
    public:
        typename TraitsP<T>::type implementation(){
            return &(Node<T, PointerAccessor, TraitsP>::data);
        }
};

template <typename T>
struct TraitsD{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
class DirectAccessor : public Node<T, DirectAccessor, TraitsD>{
    public:
        typename TraitsD<T>::type implementation(){
            T ret = Node<T, DirectAccessor, TraitsD>::data;
            return ret;
        }
};

int main(){
    auto np = new PointerAccessor<double>();
    double* p = np->get();
    cout << *p << endl;

    auto np2 = new DirectAccessor<double>();
    double d = np2->get();
    cout << d << endl;
}
```

What might seem strange about this solution is PointerAccessor being derived by Node\<..., PointerAccessor, ...>. This is the so called [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)